# Numpy array, multiply and sum over specific axis

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an array A such that

```
A = np.array([
    [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]],
    [[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]],
    [[5,5,5,5],[6,6,6,6]]
])
```

where the shape is something like (3,2,4) in this example. Now let's say I have another array B such that

```
B = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

I would like to multiply A and B element wise along the last axis of A and sum, such that

```
C = np.array([
    [10,20],
    [30,40],
    [50,60]
])
```

Is there a nice way to do this? I thought about making an equivalent 3D array out of B, doing element wise multiplication, and summing along the last axis of this new array. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

Edit: If it makes things easier, A can also be written just as

```
A = np.array([
    [1,2],
    [3,4],
    [5,6]
])
```

I made A in the way shown at the top of my post because I thought it was neccessary to do so for the proposed multiplication and summation. If working with this version of A at the bottom of this post is easier/just as easy then that would be preferable.

Cheers

Comment: You can do this operation with einsum: `np.einsum("ijk, k -> ij", A, B)`

Comment: can you provide a less ambiguous example? For example `A = np.arange(24).reshape((3, 2, 4))`

Answer (score 0):

Your example is ambiguous and how you break down the computation is unclear.

It looks to me that you could take any element of the last dimension of A and multiply it with the sum of B:

```
A[...,0]*B.sum()
```

Or do you want to sum afterwards?

```
(A*B[None,:]).sum(2)
```

output:

```
array([[10, 20],
       [30, 40],
       [50, 60]])
```

Comment: Hi, please see my edit! I assumed that I would have to form array A in the way that I did for the multiplication and summation to be possible. If this is not the case, I can just leave A as shown in the bottom of my post if that is easier :)

Comment: @P227 then simply `A*B.sum()`, i.e. `A*10`?

Comment: In this simple case, yes this works :) However I am struggling a bit. Say for example A was instead of the shape (65,65) and B was of the shape (12,). If I would try to do A*B I would get 'operands cannot be broadcast together with shapes (65,65) (12,) which does not make sense to me as in my previous example I can multiply shapes (3,2) and (4,) together. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the output for `A = np.arange(24).reshape((3, 2, 4))` and `B = np.array([10,20,30,40])`?

Comment: Hi, so if I do A*B.sum() with these arrays I get ``` [[[0 100 200 300][400 500 600 700]] [[800 900 100 1100][1200 1300 1400 1500]][[1600 1700 1800 1900][2000 2100 2200 2300]]]```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [126]: A = np.array([
     ...:     [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]],
     ...:     [[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]],
     ...:     [[5,5,5,5],[6,6,6,6]]
     ...: ])
In [127]: A.shape
Out[127]: (3, 2, 4)
In [128]: B = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

(3,2,4) broadcasts with (4,) (e.g (1,1,4)) to make (3,2,4), then sum on 4:

```
In [129]: (A*B).sum(axis=-1)
Out[129]: 
array([[10, 20],
       [30, 40],
       [50, 60]])
```

If the start is (3,2):

```
In [130]: A1 = np.array([
     ...:     [1,2],
     ...:     [3,4],
     ...:     [5,6]
     ...: ])
     ...:
```

make it (3,2,1):

```
In [132]: (A1[:,:,None]*B).shape
Out[132]: (3, 2, 4)
In [133]: (A1[:,:,None]*B).sum(axis=-1)
Out[133]: 
array([[10, 20],
       [30, 40],
       [50, 60]])
```